# json2csv is not a function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js help me to solve this question..
 In node.js it is showing like json2csv is not a function ..
 But i installed all packages of json2csv ...
 in node cmd "npm install json2csv" i did ..

```
        var json2csv = require('json2csv');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var json = [
          {
            "car": "Audi",
            "price": 40000,
            "color": "blue"
          }, {
            "car": "BMW",
            "price": 35000,
            "color": "black"
          }, {
            "car": "Porsche",
            "price": 60000,
            "color": "green"
          }
        ];
        json2csv({data: json, fields: ['car', 'price', 'color']}, function(err, csv) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('file saved');
          });
        });
    
    




    `
    json2csv({data: json, fields: ['car', 'price', 'color']}, function(err, csv) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use this:

```
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;

const csv = json2csv(json, fields);
console.log(csv);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is changed from version 3.x, but include `.parse;` will make it compatible with last version ( 4.x at the moment ).

Comment: @UJIndia I think you can try & catch.

Comment: Yeah I always write under try catch block but it is not going to try catch instead it returns a string containing error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you referred the documentation https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#json2csv-parser-synchronous-api about how to use the api ?

Comment: For some reason I had trouble finding this specific link. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const json2csv = require('json2csv');

const csv = await json2csv.parse(json, fields);
console.log(csv);
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jsonocsv is an event emitter so you have to use on some specific events for example

```
json2csv
  .on('header', header => console.log(header))
  .on('line', line => console.log(line))
  .on('error', err => console.log(err));
```

These threee are some of the emitter which trigger your function to run 
I think you will find what you want in the doucmentation examples and options section of the 
[json2csv documentation](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv)